# Get those items which are ordered after they have been delivered

Tags: mysql

I have two `tables`, namely itemOrders and itemDelivered.

> itemOrders

```
+-------+---------+--------+
| id    | orderid | itemid |
+-------+---------+--------+
| 1     | 1       | 1      |
| 2     | 1       | 2      |
| 3     | 2       | 1      |
| 4     | 2       | 2      |
| 5     | 3       | 1      |
| 6     | 3       | 2      |
+-------+---------+--------+
```

And

> itemDelivered

```
+-------+-------------+--------+
| id    | orderId     | itemid |
+-------+-------------+--------+
| 1     | 2           | 2      |
| 2     | 3           | 2      |
| 3     | 2           | 1      |
+-------+-------------+--------+
```

From the above scenario I want all those `distinct` items whose `max` orderId in the `table` itemDelivered is less than `max` orderId in the `table` itemOrders.

In the above example I should get itemid 1 as the result, as it's `max` orderid is 2 in `table` itemDelivered, which is less than its `max` orderid in `table` itemOrders which is 3.

I wrote the following `query` but it gives me both the items, 1 and 2 as item No. 2 doesn't have orderId 1 in itemDelivered `table`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT( itemid )
FROM   itemorders
WHERE  orderid NOT IN (SELECT orderid
                       FROM   itemdelivered)
```

Comment: 'less than its max orderid in table itemOrders which is 3.' - there is no itemid 3 in itemorders for orderid 1.

Comment: @P.Salmon, `orderid` column and not `itemid` column.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function. It takes no arguments, so those parentheses are not doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `LEFT JOIN` between the two table using `itemid`, and `GROUP BY` on the `itemid`.

Eventually use `HAVING` clause to consider only those `itemid` values, where `MAX(itemdelivered.orderid) < MAX(itemorders.orderid)`

**[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/beAPvSrTi8ZnT8LR5sZrwv/2)**

```
SELECT io.itemid
FROM itemorders AS io 
LEFT JOIN itemdelivered AS id 
  ON id.itemid = io.itemid 
GROUP BY io.itemid 
HAVING MAX(id.orderid) < MAX(io.orderid) 
    OR MAX(id.orderid) IS NULL
```

**Result**

```
| itemid |
| ------ |
| 1      |
```

---

Comment: your query works if "itemid" 1 exists in "itemdelivered" `table`, if "itemid" 1 doesn't exist, then the result is blank.

Comment: @abbas you can simply change `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`. your problem statement did not mention about this possible case.

Comment: `insert into itemdelivered(orderid, itemid) values (2,2),(3,2);` If you have this query in DB Fiddle, then the output is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, manage to write a query which gives the desired output.

```
SELECT io.itemid 
    FROM itemorders as io 
    LEFT JOIN itemdelivered AS id ON io.orderid = id.orderid AND io.itemid = id.itemid 
    WHERE id.itemid IS NULL 
    HAVING MAX(id.orderid) IS NULL 
    ORDER BY io.id
```

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, I have commented on your answer.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya; replied your answer.